# WritableImage to BitmapImage for Windows Phone

Tags: image

I have a problem with `WriteableImage` conversion.

I create a `WriteableImage` to process its pixcel, then i want to create a `BitmapImage` with `WriteableImage` data, but not success... Some functions are not support for windows phone.

Any ideas, some one  ?

Answer (score 0):

**BitmapImage** is not a read-only version of a **WriteableBitamp**, as we would normally expect. (From the BitmapImage documentation: "The BitmapImage can be used to reference images in the JPEG and PNG file formats." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.105).aspx)

So, probably the only way to make the "conversion" is to use **WriteableBitmap.SaveJpeg** to save on a memory stream and then load it to a **BitmapImage** via **SetSource**. This is not a good practice, so if possible I would use WritableBitmaps all the way and avoid conversion.